# Hamburger button not opening NavigationUI navigation drawer on Android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, navigation, navigation-drawer

I am attempting to use [NavigationUI](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui) to create a navigation drawer in my app. I am trying to follow the Android Developers implementation at the above link to a tee. However, one issue I am facing is that I am unable to get the hamburger button in the action bar to open/close my navigation drawer. This probably has to do with the way I override `onSupportNavigateUp()` in my `CategoryActivity`, but I'm unsure how to fix.

I hate to throw this much code at someone, but can someone with experience with the API take a look if I am missing something? Much appreciated. Thanks.

My navigation graph (`nav_graph_category.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph_category"
    app:startDestination="@id/people_fragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/people_fragment"
        android:name="com.davidread.starwarsdatabase.view.EmptyFragment"
        android:label="@string/people_category_label" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/films_fragment"
        android:name="com.davidread.starwarsdatabase.view.EmptyFragment"
        android:label="@string/films_category_label" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/starships_fragment"
        android:name="com.davidread.starwarsdatabase.view.EmptyFragment"
        android:label="@string/starships_category_label" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/vehicles_fragment"
        android:name="com.davidread.starwarsdatabase.view.EmptyFragment"
        android:label="@string/vehicles_category_label" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/species_fragment"
        android:name="com.davidread.starwarsdatabase.view.EmptyFragment"
        android:label="@string/species_category_label" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/planets_fragment"
        android:name="com.davidread.starwarsdatabase.view.EmptyFragment"
        android:label="@string/planets_category_label" />

</navigation>
```

My drawer menu (`drawer_menu_category.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:title="@string/categories_label">

        <menu>

            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/people_category_action"
                    android:title="@string/people_category_label" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/films_category_action"
                    android:title="@string/films_category_label" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/starships_category_action"
                    android:title="@string/starships_category_label" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/vehicles_category_action"
                    android:title="@string/vehicles_category_label" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/species_category_action"
                    android:title="@string/species_category_label" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/planets_category_action"
                    android:title="@string/planets_category_label" />

            </group>

        </menu>

    </item>

</menu>
```

My main layout (`activity_category.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".view.CategoryActivity">

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_category" />

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu_category" />

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</layout>
```

My main activity (`activity_category.xml`):

```
package com.davidread.starwarsdatabase.view

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.ui.*
import com.davidread.starwarsdatabase.R
import com.davidread.starwarsdatabase.databinding.ActivityCategoryBinding

class CategoryActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val binding: ActivityCategoryBinding by lazy {
        ActivityCategoryBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    }

    private val navController: NavController by lazy {
        val navHostFragment: NavHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        navHostFragment.navController
    }

    private val appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration by lazy {
        AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph, binding.drawerLayout)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        binding.navigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

A snippet from my build.gradle dependencies, in case it's a version thing:

```
dependencies {
    // Material Components library. Contains modular and customizable Material Design UI components.
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'

    // Android Jetpack's Navigation API. Required for navigation drawer.
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3"
}
```

Lastly, some screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Note, I am able to open the navigation drawer by swiping from the left side of the screen as expected. That is why navigation drawer is open in second screenshot.

Comment: If you put a log message in `onSupportNavigateUp`, does that method get called when you tap the hamburger icon?

Comment: Yes it does get called. I've tried different variations of `navigateUp` as well with no solution. There are surprisingly not a lot of these navigation drawer examples that use NavigationUI in the way I am attempting to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_category)
```

What that means is that you are inflating a brand new copy of `R.layout.activity_category` - you aren't actually using your `binding` variable at all, which means that the `binding.drawerLayout` you've set on your `AppBarConfiguration` isn't actually the `DrawerLayout` that you've set as your content view.

Instead, you'll want to actually set your `binding` as the content view of your activity by using the code from the [data binding documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/generated-binding#create):

```
setContentView(binding.root)
```

Comment: I spent HOURS on this just for it to be view binding related. Thanks so much for the help!